# Jquery Collapsible / expandable div's contnet is wrapping into the next column on a 3 column page

Tags: css

I've got this page with a 3 column div using css3 columns. inside the div are collapsible / expandable unordered lists. some of them are so long that when they expand the list items wrap into the next column. this just seems kind of funky and I was wondering if somone had a better alternative solution to display all this data that would look better. Is there anyway to keep it from going into the next column and just have that column automatically get taller?

Here is a link to my page

http://tinyurl.com/afuswcs

(Also notice how when clicking one on the second or third column near the top, it jumps to the previous column after expanding)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".wine-type-list-ul").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".tax-term-heading").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".wine-type-list-ul").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
</script>
<style> h5 {cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; ;color:#BE883B; font-size:14pt; padding-bottom:none; margin-bottom:none;  padding-left:10%;} 
.wine-type-list-ul{display:block;}
.wine-type-list-li{width:100%; display:block;padding-left:10%;}
.winery-by-wine-types {}
</style>
<?php


$post_type = 'wineries';
$tax = 'wine-types';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax,'hide_empty=0');
//list the taxonomy


echo'<div style="clear:both;" class="winery-by-wine-types">';?>
<p align="center" style="padding-bottom:10px; word-spacing:2px; padding-top:20px; font-size:16pt; color:#BEB585;">Full List of Wineries by Wine Types:</p>
<?php
echo '<style>.wine-type-list {font-size:11pt;}</style>
<div style="-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;"> 
';
//list everything
if ($tax_terms) {
  foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => $post_type,
      "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
      'orderby'=>'title' ,
       'order'=>'ASC' 
    );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {



 echo "<h5 class=\"tax-term-heading\" id=\"".$tax_term->slug."\"> $tax_term->name </h5><ul class=\"wine-type-list-ul\">";
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="wine-type-list-li"><a class="wine-type-list" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
      endwhile;

      echo'<p></ul>';



    }

    wp_reset_query();
  }echo'</div></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use columns for that. Split the elements i three in the PHP code and put a DIV tags around each elements. Then put some style on the DIV's to float them to the left:

```
    <div style="float:left;width:33.33%";>
```

Remember to make a DIV at the end ore use clearfix class on the wrapper for the  tags:

```
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Your example fixed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".wine-type-list-ul").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".tax-term-heading").click(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).next(".wine-type-list-ul").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    h5 {cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; ;color:#BE883B; font-size:14pt; padding-bottom:none; margin-bottom:none;  padding-left:10%;} 
    .wine-type-list-ul{display:block;}
    .wine-type-list-li{width:100%; display:block;padding-left:10%;}
    .winery-by-wine-types {}
</style>
<?php

    $post_type = 'wineries';
    $tax = 'wine-types';
    $tax_terms = get_terms($tax,'hide_empty=0');
            //list the taxonomy


    echo'<div style="clear:both;" class="winery-by-wine-types">';
?>

<p align="center" style="padding-bottom:10px; word-spacing:2px; padding-top:20px; font-size:16pt; color:#BEB585;">Full List of Wineries by Wine Types:</p>

<?php
    echo '<style>.wine-type-list {font-size:11pt;}</style><div><div style="float:left;width:33.33%">';

    //list everything
    if ($tax_terms)
    {
        $totalLength = count($tax_terms);
        $splittedLength = $totalLength / 3;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term)
        {
            $i++;

            $args=array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
                'orderby'=>'title' ,
                'order'=>'ASC' 
                );

            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if( $my_query->have_posts() )
            {
                if ($i == $splittedLength)
                {
                    if ($i != 1)
                    {
                        echo '</div>';
                    }

                    if ( $i != $totalLength )
                    {
                        echo '<div style="float:left;width:33.33%">';
                    }
                }

                echo "<h5 class=\"tax-term-heading\" id=\"".$tax_term->slug."\"> $tax_term->name </h5><ul class=\"wine-type-list-ul\">";

                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

?>
                <li class="wine-type-list-li"><a class="wine-type-list" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php

                the_title();


                echo'</a></li>';

                endwhile;

                echo'<p></ul>';

                if ($i == $splittedLength)
                {
                    $i = 0;
                }
            }

            wp_reset_query();
        }

        echo'</div></div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can I split the results into three seperate divs with php? It is all being generated via one wordpress query. So I could request the total amount of unordered lists, then say 1/3 in the first div 1/3 in the second div and 1/3 in the third div?

Comment: For some reason it is only splitting some of the results into three columns. http://tinyurl.com/bswpmu7 (password:tommy)

Comment: Sorry, i can see my example didn't work. I have updated the example again. Try it now. It's hard to code PHP in blind :)